# Share a File Between Communities

Tags: community, sharing, files, libraries

I have files that were uploaded to the Asset Library for a Community by adding them to the Rich Content component on a Community page.  When I look at the File's sharing settings, I can see that it is shared with the original Community.  I want to be able to share it with a new Community.  I don't see an option to do that.  I can share it with libraries, etc. but not an option to share it with another Community.  This is a problem because the original Community is deactivated and users don't have access to it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a batchable that swaps 1 Id for the other. Something like this:

```
global class BatchableCommunityShares implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful {
    global static Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext ctx) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([
            SELECT ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId, ShareType
            FROM ContentDocumentLink
            WHERE LinkedEntityId = 'OldCommunityId'
        ]);
    }

    global static void execute(Database.BatchableContext ctx, List<SObject> scope) {
        for (SObject obj : scope) {
            ContentDocumentLink cdl = (ContentDocumentLink) obj;
            cdl.LinkedEntityId = 'NewCommunityId';
        }

        update scope;
        // Disclaimer, it might not let you update the CDLs
        // If you have issues try to create new links and insert them instead
    }

    global static void finish(Database.BatchableContext ctx) {

    }
}
```

Then you can call it in anonymous apex:

```
BatchableCommunityShares batch = new BatchableCommunityShares();
Database.executeBatch(batch);
```

Alternatively, We use [DBAmp](https://forceamp.com/) to do large scale etl. Inserting/updating new contentdocumentlinks via etl would be easy enough.

Comment: Thank you!  I will give it a try tomorrow.

Answer (score -1):

Each Content of Asset Library is a record of "Content Version" object; and for each Content Version record, there is ContentDocument record. Now, we can share a ContentDocument Record with user, group or community by creating a record of ContentDocumentLink.

Now you can move all file using batch or script using anonymous window.

Here are steps for POC:

1. Get id of content version by reaching to Asset Library --> Open that file --> Copy Id from URL.
2. Query ContentDocument Id as below

   `String conDocId = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = '<content id from 1st step>'].ContentDocumentId;`
3. Get community Id and pass as LinkedEntityId below:

   `ContentDocumentLink cdLink  = new ContentDocumentLink ();
   cdLink.ShareType = 'V';
   cdLink.ContentDocumentId    = '<Document Id>'; //from second step
   cdLink.LinkedEntityId = '<community id>';
   insert cdLink ;`

Comment: Can you edit and add proper code formating?

Comment: My concern with your answer is that it's half manual half code; as written, it would require updating the shares one by one. Review my answer for a bulk approach options.

Comment: Man!  question was can we share files in community....my answer explained how can you do that ....given code is just for POC .... I doubt on people who mark such answer negative.